# how to use .iloc with .isnull()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am asked to use the .isnull () function to verify the missing values on your DataFrame. Then print the first 10 rows of your data without using the .head () function. You may use the .loc () or iloc() functions. Do not store the selected data to any DataFrame, you just want to view. View the first 10 rows of your data.

I coded as:

```
biz.isnull().iloc[0,10]
```

but it shows IndexError:

> single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

what should i code to output a dataframe with .isnull()implemented?

Comment: `biz[biz.isnull()].iloc[0,10]`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the first 10 rows should be retrieved as in `biz.iloc[:10]` or `biz.iloc[0:10]` rather than comma-separated.

`biz.isnull().iloc[:10]` gives you if each element in biz's first 10 rows is null.
`biz[biz.isnull()]` takes everything that is null thus returning matrix of null only.
`any(biz.isnull())` verifies the integrity of matrix.
`biz[biz.isnull()] = -1` assigns a default value to every null value in the df.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should understand the indexing of data frame. 
In your case:

```
biz.iloc[:10]
```

this will print first 10 rows of the data frame,see

```
dataframe.iloc[: , :]

             /       \
this is for rows       this is for columns
```

Now if you want to calculate how much missing values are there in each columns, you can use

```
dataframe.isnull().sum(axis=0)
```